# Problemas com ordenação por data no DataTables

Tags: php, html, jquery, jquery-datatables

Olá.
Sei que existem diversos tópicos aqui no Stack, porém já tentei todas as opções sugeridas nas respostas e não obtive êxito.

O meu problema é que quando clico no cabeçalho da tabela para ordená-la por **data** (após os dados virem do php e exibidos pelo **DataTables**), essa ordenação sai toda desorganizada. Para que está ordenando pela String e não pela questão da data. Vou postar aqui o código que estou utilizando.

**Lembrando que já tentei essas opções abaixo: (de incluir essas bibliotecas e não obtive sucesso)**

```html
<!-- INCLUÍDO POR MIM ATRAVÉS DE PESQUISA -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.10/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>
```

**Meu código:**

```js
//DATA TABLE DA PÁGINA
$.fn.dataTable.moment('dd/mm/YYYY');

$('#resultado-listagem-notificacoes-recentes').DataTable({


  "processing": true,
  "serverSide": true,
  "ajax": {
    "url": "../banco/banco-get/pagina-listagem-notificacoes-recentes/php-arquivos-disponiveis.php",
    "type": "POST",

    "data": function(item) {
      //item.empresa = $('#empresa_relatorio').val();
      //item.departamento = $('#departamento_relatorio').val();
      //item.empresa_origem = $('#empresa_origem_relatorio').val();
      //item.cod = $('#cod_relatorio').val();
      //item.atividade = $('#tipo_atividade_relatorio').val();
      //item.estatus = $('#status_relatorio').val();
      // item.ano = $('#ano_relatorio').val();

    }
  },

  paging: true,
  scrollX: true,
  scrollCollapse: true,
  scrollY: "450px",
  scrollX: "900px",
  "order": [
    [3, "desc"]
  ],

  "language": {
    "lengthMenu": "Mostrando _MENU_ registros por página",
    "zeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado com estes parâmetros de pesquisa",
    //"info": "Mostrando página _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
    "info": "Listagem dos Registros",
    "infoEmpty": "Nenhum registro disponível",
    "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de _MAX_ registros no total)",
    "search": "Pesquisar:",
    "paginate": {
      "first": "Primeiro",
      "last": "Último",
      "next": "Próximo",
      "previous": "Anterior"
    },
  }

});


var table = $('#resultado-listagem-notificacoes-recentes').DataTable();
```

```html
<?php

session_start();
require_once("../../conexao/conexao-com-banco.php");

 
//Receber a requisão da pesquisa 
$requestData = $_REQUEST; 


//Indice da coluna na tabela visualizar resultado => nome da coluna no banco de dados
$columns = array( 
 0 => 'titulo',
 1 => 'corpo',
 2 => 'autor', 
 3 => 'data_aviso',
 4 => 'horario'
);


//Obtendo registros de número total sem qualquer pesquisa
$contadorderegistros = "SELECT titulo,corpo,autor,DATE_FORMAT(data_aviso, '%d-%m-%Y') AS data_aviso,horario ";
$contadorderegistros .= "FROM tbl_avisos WHERE destinatario = '$usuario_logado'";


$resultado_arquiv = mysqli_query($conecta, $contadorderegistros);
$qnt_linhas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_arquiv);


$dadosparapreenchimento = "SELECT titulo,corpo,autor,DATE_FORMAT(data_aviso, '%d-%m-%Y') AS data_aviso,horario ";
$dadosparapreenchimento .= "FROM tbl_avisos WHERE destinatario = '$usuario_logado'";



if( !empty($requestData['search']['value']) ) {   // se houver um parâmetro de pesquisa, $requestData['search']['value'] contém o parâmetro de pesquisa
   // $dadosparapreenchimento.=" and responsavel LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%'";
 $dadosparapreenchimento.=" or titulo LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%'";
    $dadosparapreenchimento.=" or corpo LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
 $dadosparapreenchimento.=" or autor LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%'";
 $dadosparapreenchimento.=" or data_aviso LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%'";
 $dadosparapreenchimento.=" or horario LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%'";

 }


$resultado_arquivos = mysqli_query($conecta, $dadosparapreenchimento);
$totalFiltered = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_arquivos);

//Ordenar o resultado
$dadosparapreenchimento .= " ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";

//ACIMA, COMENTAMOS PARA COLOCAR O ORDER BY COM O NOSSO CRITÉRIO, QUE É A DATA DE UPLOAD (QUE ESTÁ NA QUERY ABAIXO)
//$dadosparapreenchimento .= " ORDER BY data_aviso desc" . " LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']." " ;


$resultado_arquivos = mysqli_query($conecta, $dadosparapreenchimento);


// Ler e criar o array de dados
$dados = array();
while( $row_arquivo = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_arquivos) ) {  
 $dado = array(); 
 //$dado[] = utf8_encode(utf8_decode($row_arquivo["responsavel"]));   //Importante usar o utf8 em campos que vão conter acento pois dara erro no JSON
 $dado[] = utf8_encode(utf8_decode($row_arquivo["titulo"]));
 //$dado[] = utf8_encode(utf8_decode($row_arquivo["departamento"]));
 $dado[] = utf8_encode(utf8_decode($row_arquivo["corpo"]));
 $dado[] = utf8_encode(utf8_decode($row_arquivo["autor"]));
 $dado[] = utf8_encode(utf8_decode($row_arquivo["data_aviso"]));
 $dado[] = utf8_encode(utf8_decode($row_arquivo["horario"]));
 $dados[] = $dado;
}

//Cria o array de informações a serem retornadas para o Javascript
$json_data = array(
 "draw" => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),//para cada requisição é enviado um número como parâmetro
 "recordsTotal" => intval( $qnt_linhas ),  //Quantidade de registros que há no banco de dados
 "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), //Total de registros quando houver pesquisa
 "data" => $dados   //Array de dados completo dos dados retornados da tabela 
);

echo json_encode($json_data);  //enviar dados como formato json


?>
```

**COMO ESTÁ SENDO EXIBIDO**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OBS: Se observarem, a data ao invés de ir de 30-09-2019 para 29-09-2019, está indo para 30-08-2019. Ou seja, me parece que está sendo ordenada como String.

Já tentei essas respostas abaixo e não consegui:

[inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148561/ordenar-campo-datetime-de-uma-datatable)

[inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100902/datatable-n%C3%A3o-ordena-corretamente)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boa tarde.

Faça a importação do plugin datasorts.js abaixo da importação da datatables.min.js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/sorting/date-eu.js"></script>
```

Abaixo das importações feitas acima, utilize o código abaixo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nome_da_tabela').DataTable( {
      "columns": [
      { "type": "date-eu" },
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null
    ],
    "order": [0, 'desc'],
    responsive: true,
    "language": {
            "decimal":        "",
            "emptyTable":     "Nada para exibir",
            "info":           "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "infoEmpty":      "Exibindo página 0 de 0 de 0 registros",
            "infoFiltered":   "(filtrado do total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "infoPostFix":    "",
            "thousands":      ",",
            "lengthMenu":     "Exibir _MENU_ registros",
            "loadingRecords": "Carregando...",
            "processing":     "Processando...",
            "search":         "Buscar:",
            "zeroRecords":    "Nenhum resultado encontrado",
            "paginate": {
                "first":      "Primeira",
                "last":       "Última",
                "next":       "Próxima",
                "previous":   "Anterior"
            },
            "aria": {
                "sortAscending":  ": activate to sort column ascending",
                "sortDescending": ": activate to sort column descending"
            }
    }
    } )
} );
</script>
```

**Explicando:** 
Observe o trecho

```
"columns": [
      { "type": "date-eu" },
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null
    ],
```

Onde há { "type": "date-eu" }, é a coluna que contém a data e que será ordenada. Caso a tabela possua mais colunas, deve ser colocado 'null' na ordem em que as colunas da tabela estão dispostas. Se o número de campos null não estiver de acordo com o número dos demais dados, a tabela não será exibida corretamente.

Este trecho de código acima por exemplo, serviria para uma tabela com as colunas:
data_nascimento | nome | idade | sexo | cidade

Caso a coluna da data seja a terceira, o código deverá ser por exemplo

```
"columns": [
      null,
      null,
      { "type": "date-eu" },
      null,
      null
    ],
```

A coluna pode ser exibida no formato dd/mm/YYYY:

```
<td><?php echo date("d/m/Y",strtotime($data['data'])); ?></td>
```

**OBS:** Só pra salientar, que se a coluna não for a primeira, como neste exemplo, temos que mudar também o **"order": [0, 'desc']** para **"order": [*numero_da_coluna*, 'desc']**.

Comment: Muito bom resposta, Leonardo. Utilizei hoje aqui e funfou de boa.

Comment: Que bom ter ajudado. Bem colocado sua observação.